# Any live moon stream?

Tags: the-moon

I searched Google for a while and of so many available cameras, I couldn't find a moon live stream video camera. Does anyone know any free website that offers this? Where can you see live the moon right now?

Comment: Do you want a view of the moon from the Earth (which won't available at all times due to the moon setting, and clouds) or a view of the moon from the moon (which doesn't exist owing to there being no functioning cameras on the moon)

Comment: @JamesK Is not the UV-camera on Chang'e 3 still working though?

Comment: Everyone here is missing the possibility of a Earth-Moon Lagrange point orbiter, such as [ARTEMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THEMIS#ARTEMIS). The moon would be constantly visible.

Answer (score 3):

Since the moon isn't visible all the time from any single camera location on Earth, such a website would have to be an aggregate of many different cameras around the world, displaying a single camera based on current time and weather conditions. Even in this scenario, there's a chance all the cameras will be obscured by clouds and there will be no view of the moon.

Such a website doesn't exist *that I know of*. Perhaps it would be an interesting project if you're interested in such a thing.